# In SQL Server - How to list all foreign keys related tables and fields?

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

I am having a problem to list all the foreign keys in a database and show the related tables & the fields from each one.

I have tried this query:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id)
    ,OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_id)
    ,OBJECT_NAME(object_id)
    ,*
FROM sys.foreign_keys
```

But this returns just the parent table and field. I need more information. Can anybody help me here?

Comment: Ok, so what's your question? What's stopping you? Why isn't what you've tried working?

Comment: My question is: HOW TO DO THIS?
I've tried some commands but none off them worked for me... This command for example:
select OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id),
OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_id),
OBJECT_NAME(object_id),
* from sys.foreign_keys
This returns the parent table, but I need the referenced too...

Comment: That should all be in your "question", Rodrigo. "I need" is not a question, that's a demand/request we do the work for you. Edit your question to be something we can answer, along with everything else.

Comment: This is on my question now. I'm knew here dude.

Comment: You say you want "more information" What addition information do you want? What are you expecting to see here?

Comment: A foreign key is a association with two tables and fields, I need that, from all table in my database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206062/discussion-between-rodrigo-machado-and-larnu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below query from the [reference](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4753/list-dependencies-for-sql-server-foreign-keys/) also the [reference](https://dataedo.com/kb/query/sql-server/list-foreign-keys).

```
-- using sys tables to enumerate foreign keys
-- returns 45 constraint rows
 SELECT
    f.name constraint_name
   ,OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) referencing_table_name
   ,COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id, fc.parent_column_id) referencing_column_name
   ,OBJECT_NAME (f.referenced_object_id) referenced_table_name
   ,COL_NAME(fc.referenced_object_id, fc.referenced_column_id) referenced_column_name
   ,delete_referential_action_desc
   ,update_referential_action_desc
FROM sys.foreign_keys AS f
INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc
   ON f.object_id = fc.constraint_object_id
ORDER BY f.name


-- using INFORMATION_SCHEMA to enumerate foreign keys
-- returns 45 constraint rows
SELECT 
    C.CONSTRAINT_NAME [constraint_name] 
   ,C.TABLE_NAME [referencing_table_name] 
   ,KCU.COLUMN_NAME [referencing_column_name] 
   ,C2.TABLE_NAME [referenced_table_name] 
   ,KCU2.COLUMN_NAME [referenced_column_name]
   ,RC.DELETE_RULE delete_referential_action_desc 
   ,RC.UPDATE_RULE update_referential_action_desc

FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS C 
       INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE KCU 
         ON C.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = KCU.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA 
            AND C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = KCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
       INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS RC 
         ON C.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = RC.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA 
            AND C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = RC.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
       INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS C2 
         ON RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = C2.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA 
            AND RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = C2.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
       INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE KCU2 
         ON C2.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = KCU2.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA 
            AND C2.CONSTRAINT_NAME = KCU2.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
            AND KCU.ORDINAL_POSITION = KCU2.ORDINAL_POSITION 
WHERE  C.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY'
ORDER BY C.CONSTRAINT_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your (underlying) question, you can find everything you need in the following system tables:

```
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS
```

Good luck!